# Проблема с передачей параметров внутрь js плагина Imperavi Redactor. Пропадает элемент массива

Tags: массивы, yii, php, javascript

Здравствуйте. У меня тут творится самая настоящая магия. Пытаюсь наладить работу одного весьма хорошего wysiwyg редактора. У редактора есть входной параметр buttons - массив имён кнопок для панели, и вот с ним творится бяда.

Вызываю я всю эту ерунду через php, а конкретно через Yii:

```
$this->widget('Redactor.ImperaviRedactorWidget', [
      'model' => $model,
      'attribute' => 'content',
      'options' => [
      'buttons' => ['html', 'bold'],
      'cleanOnPaste' => FALSE
   ]
]);
```

Yii генерирует мне абсолютно корректную строчку вызова:

```
jQuery('#KbContent_content').redactor({'lang':'ru','imageUpload':'/site/uploadFiles','buttons':['html','bold'],'cleanOnPaste':false,'plugins':['fullscreen']});
```

Но кнопка html, то бишь исходный код, не появляется. Тогда я добавил console.log() в конструктор этого редактора и, пардон, очешуел. Добавил вот так:

```
$.fn.redactor = function(options)
    {
                console.log(options);
        var val = [];
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
```

и там потом ещё много кода, но он не важен, на сколько я понимаю. То есть функция принимает в себя объект и тут же выводит его в консоль. Вот что видно в консоли:
[image]

Из массива buttons пропал элемент html. И, что ещё интересно, в кратком выводе объекта (первая строка) buttons описан как массив из 2-х элементов, а в полном выводе (вторая строка) как из одного.

Эксперименты показали:

- если в buttons передать только bold - 
  всё работает правильно;
- если поменять местами bold и html - 
  результат не изменится;
- если передать только html на входе в
  плагин buttons пуст (та же ерунда - в
  кратком Array(1) в полном Array(0));
- если html передать дважды (['html',
  'html', 'bold']), то он таки
  появляется в массиве buttons на входе
  в плагин, но это ж костыль какой-то
  невозможный вообще.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной магией? В чём может быть дело?

Comment: Скриншот консоли получился очень маленьким, но если открыть его в новой вкладке, то всё видно

Answer (score 1):

На самом сайте редактора есть вот такой интересный код: http://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/buttons-source/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    $('#redactor').redactor({
        focus: true,
        buttonSource: true
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Добавление этого параметра действительно решило задачу) Судя по всему, где-то внутри модуля была отложенная фильтрация входящих параметров?